Unity android faild
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 13 seconds (13402 ms)
    Building Player failed
    0x00007ff7e6c9957d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
    0x00007ff7e6c9e629 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
    0x00007ff7e7c8a701 (Unity) GetStacktrace
    0x00007ff7e834460e (Unity) DebugStringToFile
    0x00007ff7e5ba6988 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
    0x000001f09b1d9ae3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
    0x000001f09b1d99fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
    0x000001f09b1d9740 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
    0x000001f0e97b92a5 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
    0x000001f128aeb863 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
    0x000001f128ae78ab (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
    0x000001f128ad103b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
    0x000001f128ac36e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
    0x000001f128aadf2b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
    0x000001f12137dee2 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
    0x000001f12137dcc3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
    0x000001f03c95ba2b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
    0x000001f10d8fc2df (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
    0x000001f03c94869b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
    0x000001f128a63ceb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
    0x000001f128a63b43 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
    0x000001f128a6368b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
    0x000001f128a63543 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
    0x000001f0e849eec3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
    0x000001f0e849ea23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
    0x000001f0e849e75f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
    0x000001f0e849e453 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
    0x000001f128a615a3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
    0x000001f0e950a38e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
    0x000001f0e9509c5b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
    0x000001f0e8488203 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
    0x000001f0e8488053 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
    0x000001f0e8487f8b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
    0x000001f0e950a133 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
    0x000001f0e9509533 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
    0x000001f0e950938b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
    0x000001f0ec641933 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
    0x000001f0ec6413c3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
    0x000001f0ec64117f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
    0x000001f0ec64109b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
    0x000001f0ec640515 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
    0x000001f0ec640656 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
    0x00007fff31cf4c1e (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
    0x00007fff31c2d254 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3068)
    0x00007fff31c2d3cc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3115)
    0x00007ff7e6bb2484 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
    0x00007ff7e6b90154 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
    0x00007ff7e6b8ac75 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
    0x00007ff7e6ce3a4a (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
    0x00007ff7e76e2cc4 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
    0x00007ff7e7cbbc40 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
    0x00007ff7e76e2bf3 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEventFromAPI
    0x00007ff7e76e2ac8 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
    0x00007ff7e7cbca7e (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
    0x00007ff7e7cb6894 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
    0x00007ff826e483f1 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
    0x00007ff826e47eb1 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
    0x00007ff7e7c90223 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
    0x00007ff7e7c95550 (Unity) WinMain
    0x00007ff7e9055cfe (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
    0x00007ff82745259d (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
    0x00007ff827bcaf38 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

I was making a question and answer game in Unity, but while making the application, I want to get an android build, but it constantly gives the above error message, so I moved my project from scratch to a new project, when I first got the first build, there was no problem, then I just added new codes to the application (new questions) and when I wanted to get the build, it gave the same error, what is the reason for this, is there a problem in my unity version or in the code?
this text is excerpted from the translation, sorry for typos
